# How to show "Get Direction" button in ionic-2 on "google maps marker"?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to build hybrid mobile app. In my native android App I have implemented "google maps marker" page successfully. In this page when user click "marker" on maps, user get option to "get direction" from the marker. this is the screenshot of my native android "Maps" page.
[Native Android app "maps" page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weB30.png)

Now, problem is i am building same "maps" page for hybrid app in IONIC-2 framework. I have successfully implemented the marker option in ionic2 hybrid app, but when i click on marker i am not getting this 2 option is my ionic2 app. I am not getting any clue to implement this.

Please suggest how to get this two option when i click on marker in the maps using IONIC-2 framework. this screenshot is from my native android app, and i am trying to implement same in ionic-2 framework. Please suggest the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting buttons because you are using Google Maps JavaScript API in hybrid app while native app uses Google Maps Android API.

The Maps JavaScript API simply doesn't have this functionality. So you should program your own [overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) similar to the Maps Android API and open [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) from it on click event.